# Firebase Database security rules without user authentication

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How to set security rules for database without user authentication in which user can change there own data only.
When app starts for the first time new data item gets added without any authentication with unique ID.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "Rand3435" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "DID" : "Rand3435",
    "CanDance" : "No"
  },
  "Rand7765" : {
    "Score" : 25,
    "DID" : "Rand7765",
    "CanDance" : "Yes"
  },
  "Rand6769" : {
    "Score" : 0,
    "DID" : "Rand6769",
    "CanDance" : "No"
  },
  "Rand1326" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "DID" : "Rand1326",
    "CanDance" : "No"
  },
  "Rand9879" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "DID" : "Rand9879",
    "CanDance" : "Yes"
  },
  "Rand5455" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "DID" : "Rand5455",
    "CanDance" : "No"
  },
  "Rand2322" : {
    "Score" : 19,
    "DID" : "Rand2322",
    "CanDance" : "No"
  }
}
```

What will be the rules in JSON format to put in the rules section?

Please help, I am new to Firebase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Store unique ID in shared preferences when app starts for first time.
2. Whenever user want to made any changes to database, check whether unique ID is present in database or not.
3. If unique ID is present, then user can modify data, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure access to a user's data, but don't want to require the user to provide credentials, you're looking for Firebase's [**anonymous** authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). With anonymous authentication you sign the user in with just this simple call:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

From there on, the user has a UID that identifies them, and you can use this UID in the data to associate data with that user, and then in security rules to ensure only authorized access is allowed as shown in the documentation on [user based security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

---

If you insist on generating your own IDs, you can ensure only someone who knows the ID can write a document with that ID with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "$DID": {
      // anyone who knows a DID can read its contents
      ".read": true, 

      // anyone who knows a DID can write its contents, as long as they specify the DID in the contents too
      ".write": "newData.child('DID').val() === $DID"
    }
  }
}
```

So this way the user must specify the same ID in both the `DID` property and in the path, to be allowed to write. Since there is no read permission on the root, there is no way for someone to get a list of all data (and hence of all DIDs).

Comment: So is it necessary to implement `signInAnonymously()` ? Can't we take `Rand3435` variable to compare current user? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: What prevents any other user from setting/using that same `Rand3435` value?

Comment: Logged in user or other user will have no knowledge about this randon number, I am not displaying this number on UI.

Comment: How will the user know what number to enter then? Btw: it's not hard to build the security rules for this, I just don't really see how this will work and be reasonably secure.

Comment: No, User will not enter anything. Only `Score` and `CanDance` gets updated based of gameplay. `DID` will generate on first login only and then it will remain same.

Comment: I added something for that, but would still recommend using anonymous authentication as it is better protected by having much higher entropy than what you shared in your question.

Comment: Why you added root read to false? Now I can not read my own data. It's not updating on UI

Comment: You don't want anyone to be able to read the root, as that'd allow them to read all DIDs. If you want anyone who knows a DID to read that data, you can add `".read" true` on *that* level in the rules. I updated my answer to show that. But note that there is no protection in this way about what nodes a user can write to. They can make up any value for DID themselves, and write to that node.

Comment: Alright, Its not working so i decided to implement `signInAnonymously` and i have done that. So instead of DID now its auth.uid. Now can you tell what will be the secure rules?

Comment: First example here should allow you to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: There is some issue after implementing `signInAnonymously`. After Uninstalling and then reinstalling uid gets changed, which is not what I wanted. So any solution in your mind?